# Matlab surfc colormap shading

Tags: matlab, colors, 3d, plot

How can I create a 3D plot that has a smooth color gradient, from the lowest value to the highest value. I have tried changing color map, but the only choice that works is the 'default', which looks awful. Most colors have a huge range (there is very poor distribution of the spectrum. Blue and red have a huge spread,and light blue and yellow are thin strips of color). Any other colormap that I chose is literally a solid color.
How can I either get other colormaps to actually show up as gradients, or define my own color map?

this is the code that I have tried

```
  surfc( X(1,:), V(1,:), (Z(:,:),'EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none','FaceLighting','phong'  );
  hold on
  shading interp
  colormap('summer');
  set(gca, 'clim', [0,5]);
```

Comment: Maybe this is already a bit too late: I would suggest using a finer resolution by manually setting the number of levels in your colormap. For example: 
    C = summer(10000); %(or some large Number)
    colormap(C);
This should probably work depending on the dynamic range of your data.